# How can I define a new type and a type for list of this type in ocaml?

Tags: types, ocaml, reason

I'm new to ocaml and have defined a type.

```
type options =
  | Rock
  | Paper
  | Scissors
```

I want to also define a list of options. This is how I'm attempting it

```
type opts = list options;
```

Merlin gives me this error when I try and pass a literal list of options into a function

[image: Options]

Any ideas? BTW I'm using ReasonML specifically though I don't think that matters.

Here's the entire function translated back to ocaml.

```
let compGuess () =
  let rec aux opts k =
    match opts with
    | [] -> [Rock]
    | x::[] -> x
    | h::t -> (match k = 1 with | true  -> h | false  -> aux t (k - 1)) in
  aux [Rock; Paper; Scissors] ((Random.int 3) + 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type problem looks to be as follows. The first alternative of your match returns something of type `opts`. Thus the second alternative must also return something of type `opts`. This implies that `x`, the head of the input, is of type `opts`. This implies that the input is a list of opts. In other words, your function should take a list of list of options. But you're passing a list of options.

Comment: Thanks, this answers everything for me!